# Does the eclipse plugin for scout sdk work?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

After updating Eclipse from version 2023-09 to version 2023-12, the template proposal service, ctrl+space, no longer works.

'Unhandled event loop exception' error always reported

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ4Y2.png)

Eclipse Scout SDK 13.0.27.

I try to reinstall the SDK. Always the same problem.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Official response:

Hi Giorgio

Sorry for the late reply!

This is a bug in the Scout Plugins for Eclipse 2023-12 :(
It has already been reported in our internal QA some weeks ago, but the fix did not make it into the final 2023-12 build because of time constraints.

However, the fix has been pushed and is currently being tested.
We will provide a bugfix release as soon as tests are successful and inform again here.

Until then you have the following workarounds:

Stay with Eclipse 2023-09. This also works if you want to use the newest Scout runtime version.
Temporary disable the Scout Template in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced

Hope this helps
Mat